# Find a string in a column and return and return an array with row numbers

Tags: excel, vba

I want to search in a column and find a string. However, there are several cells with that string and I want to return an array that contains all row position.

```
Dim r As Range
Set r = Sheets("Sheet3").columns(3).Find(What:="TEST", LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
```

this return only the first row, but not all.
How can I return all of rows that contain "TEST"?
Thanks.

Comment: Is that the final output or are you going to use those references to return something else in the end?

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick...

It will loop through `Column 3` of `Sheet3` to produce an array containing the row numbers of every occurrence of `TEXT`.  Based on the options used in your example, it is case sensitive and must occupy the whole cell.

```
Sub demo_FindIntoArray()
    Const searchFor = "TEST" 'case sensitive whole-cell search term
    Const wsName = "Sheet3" 'worksheet name to search
    Const colNum = 3 'column# to search
    Dim r As Range, firstAddress As String, strTxt As String, arrRows
    With Sheets("Sheet3").Columns(3)
        Set r = .Find(searchFor, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
        If Not r Is Nothing Then
            firstAddress = r.Address
            Do
                If strTxt <> "" Then strTxt = strTxt & ","
                strTxt = strTxt & r.Row
                Set r = .FindNext(r)
            Loop While Not r Is Nothing And r.Address <> firstAddress
        End If
    End With

    If strTxt <> "" Then
        arrRows = Split(strTxt,",")
        MsgBox "Found " & UBound(arrRows)+1 & " occurrences of '" & searchFor & "':" & vbLf & vbLf & strTxt
    Else
        MsgBox "'" & searchFor & "' was not found."
    End If

    '[arrRows] is now an array containing row numbers

End Sub
```

It works by first building a string with a comma separated list of values, and then using the [`Split` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/split-function) to split it into an array.

Answer (score 0):

This will unionize the ranges that equal "Test",

```
Sub SelectA1()
    Dim FrstRng As Range
    Dim UnionRng As Range
    Dim c As Range
    Set FrstRng = Range("C:C").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 23)

    For Each c In FrstRng.Cells
        If LCase(c) = "test" Then
            If Not UnionRng Is Nothing Then
                Set UnionRng = Union(UnionRng, c)    'adds to the range
            Else
                Set UnionRng = c
            End If
        End If
    Next c

    UnionRng.Select    ' or whatever you want to do with it.
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't indicate what you want to do with the results.  However, you can return an array of the row numbers **containing** the word "TEST" with a worksheet formula:

Case Insensitive:

```
=AGGREGATE(15,6,SEARCH("TEST",$C:$C)*ROW($C:$C),ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & COUNTIF($C:$C,"*TEST*"))))
```

Case Sensitive:

```
=AGGREGATE(15,6,FIND("TEST",$C:$C)*ROW($C:$C),ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(FIND("TEST",$C:$C))))))
```

Case Insensitive; cell = test (eg entire cell contents):

```
=AGGREGATE(15,6,1/($C:$C="test")*ROW($C:$C),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&COUNTIF($C:$C,"test"))))
```

If you want to use this array for something else, such as to return the contents of the rows where the third column = "test", you could also do this with a filter, either in VBA or on the worksheet.

There are many different appropriate solutions, depending on what you are going to do with the results of these row numbers.